# Check if a country is needed for a critical amount of votes

Tags: prolog

Hey guys I'm new to prolog and learning it myself. 
I found this question on the internet but without any answers.

I have this database

```
countries([belgium, france, germany, italy, luxembourg, netherlands]). 

weight(france, 4). 
weight(germany, 4).
weight(italy, 4). 
weight(belgium, 2). 
weight(netherlands, 2). 
weight(luxembourg, 1). 
threshold(12).
```

Now I  made this program to see if a list of countries have enough votes to get over the threshold.

```
winning([], 0).

winning([Head | Tail], N):-
    weight(Head, N1),
    winning(Tail, N2),
    N is N1 + N2.

winning(Y):-
    winning(Y, N),      
    threshold(X),
    N >= X.
```

Now I need to write a program critical/2, first argument a country, second argument a list of countries. Is the first country needed to get over the threshold or not.

example:

```
?- critical(netherlands, [belgium, france, germany]). 
   True
?- critical(netherlands, [france, germany, italy]). 
   False
```

for this program I need to check first, if the second argument is winning already. And if so it will fail. If not i need to get the value of the first argument add it to the second value and then check if its over the threshold. If it won't be enough it will fail. If it is enough it will succeed.

```
 critical(X,Y):-
    winning(Y,N),
    weight(X,Value),
    N1 is N+Value,
    threshold(X),
    N1 >= X.
```

I'm doing alot of things wrong here but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close to the solution. A few hints:

First, a good naming convention helps you keep track of which argument is what:

`critical(C, Cs) :-`

This makes clear that the first argument is a single country, and the second is a list of zero or more countries.

So, let us first relate `Cs` to their total weight. Again, it helps to have a good naming convention, making clear which argument is what:

```
country_weight(france,      4). 
country_weight(germany,     4).
country_weight(italy,       4). 
country_weight(belgium,     2). 
country_weight(netherlands, 2). 
country_weight(luxembourg,  1)
```

Now, to relate multiple countries to their respective weights, we use the meta-predicate `maplist/3`:

```
maplist(country_weight, Cs, Ws)
```

and to sum the weights, we use `sum_list/2`:

```
sum_list(Ws, Sum)
```

It is obvious how to describe that `Sum` must be below the threshold (left as an exercise).

Finally, to denote that the sum *plus* the weight of the country denoted by the first argument is greater than the threshould, we use:

```
country_weight(C, W),
W + Sum > Threshold
```

This completes the definition. Notice that it was not necessary to describe which countries exist at all. Therefore, you can omit the first predicate of your program.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, I understand what to do, just add threshold(X) and sum<X, and I got it working. But why don't you use the winning program, instead of the maplist, and sum_list, I was wondering how to do it in that way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just want to show you `maplist/3` to spare you the effort of manually writing such recursions. You have already shown in the code above that you can do it yourself if necessary. And `sum_list/2` is an efficient library predicate: Check out its definition, it is tail recursive and thus consumes less local stack space in comparison to your version.